# MobileFirst - Use PHP / call RPG

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

i have two small questions about the mobilefirst- Server.

I found out, that the mobilefirst (or Worklight)-Server doesn't support PHP.
([IBM Worklight 6.0 - How to include a PHP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22152633/ibm-worklight-6-0-how-to-include-a-php-file))
Is that still so? Or is there any plan to include PHP?

Then I want to call RPG's with an Java-Adapter.
But I doesn't find any full example for calling a RPG.
Also I want to call RPG's with a Display File. Is that possible?
In the following article it sounds like it is easily possible:
http://www.it-zoom.de/dv-dialog/e/vom-greenscreen-zum-touchscreen-10865/

Comment: This is two separate questions. Please ask them separately.

Answer (score 1):

IBM MobileFirst server sits on top of a WebSphere Java EE based App Server. The MobileFirst Platform Adapter pattern is a server-side layer that provides abstraction to any generalized end-point; including PHP, SQL, SAP, whatever.  So as long as your final endpoint is capable of acting as a "service", accepting HTTP requests, and producing JSON/XML responses, this pattern should work fine.  The basic flow is:

1. mobile app client calls the MFP adapter
2. adapter calls the final endpoint (PHP/RPG in your case)
3. Endpoint responds with JSON/XML data
4. Adapter optionally converts response to JSON
5. Mobile client app receives and processes (displays) a consistent response from the adapter.

Hope this helps clarify the pattern for you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP is a *server-side* HTML rendering technology. MobileFirst is (partly) for building hybrid mobile applications, which run on the client (mobile), so PHP wouldn't be relevant.

I'm not sure what an RPG is. Please can you specify the acronym in your question?

Comment: Role Playing Game, Andrew... you should know this. :-)

Comment: With RPG i mean the programming language (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) - not the Role Playing Game :-D

And as i've read, mobileFirst / Worklight has also an Java based Server?